# java error ".class expected"

Tags: java, methods, compilation, call

I am trying to call a method which calculate the average value in java. But when I compile it always output `'.class' expected` when it came to the line:
System.out.println("Average: " + Average(double Value[]));

Here's my code:

```
public class q2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    { 
        new q2().InputValue();
    }

public void InputValue() throws IOException
{  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    double[] Value = new double[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value: ");
        Value[i] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println("Average: " + Average(double Value[]));
}

public double Average(double Value[])
{  
    double average = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        average = average + Value[n];
    }
    average = average / 10;
    return average;
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you really calling this way, Average(double Value[])?
Are is it typo?

Comment: By the way: In Java variable and method names usually start with a lower-case letter, so your methods should be `inputValue()` and `average()` and `double[] Value` should be `double[] value` (or even more fitting `values`).

Answer (score 7):

This is the bit that's failing:

```
 "Average: " + Average(double Value[])
```

The `double Value[]` bit should be an argument for the method, e.g.

```
"Average: " + Average(Value)
```

I would strongly recommend that you start following normal Java naming conventions, e.g. naming classes with PascalCase, methods and variables with camelCase. Also, given that your `Value` variable actually holds multiple values, I'd pluralize it to `values`. You'd be amazed at how much easier code is to read when the names are chosen well :)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Use the List Interface with an ArrayList whenever you need an Array. It saves you from making stupid mistakes.